# Linear algebra- Simplify matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let A, B and C be invertible matrices of order (n x n). Determine the matrix that is obtained when the expression is simplified

[image]

I think the answer is
$C^{-1} BC$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, heads up it is a general rule is too show some work on a problem or you risk being down-voted

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**  You can use the fact that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ to derive the result.